# Applying a for loop over multiple vectors

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, vector, apply

I am attempting to iterate a for loop where 3 different vectors are being called. More specifically, I am attempting to look at how long different sites take to reach their carrying capacity. Essentially, I want to determine how long it takes different populations to reach their respective carrying capacities.

As of right now, I have it set up to successfully print the abundances at different time steps.

```
tspan <- 80
N <- matrix(0,tspan,1)
N[1] <- 20
K <- 13626
r <- 0.32

for (t in 2:tspan){
    N[t] <- N[t-1]*exp(r*(1-N[t-1]/K))
    print(N)
  }
```

Although even this results in an output of the same vector printed out N=tspan times. The end goal here is to iterate the above for loop over a vector of different K values:

```
K<-c(208, 543, 557, 831, 831, 878, 933, 970, 1022, 1039)
```

and then have all of those stored in a data frame. I have tried using a nested for loop, but I am not sure how to accomplish that, as all necessary values are references in the 1 equation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `sapply`

```
K <- c(208, 543, 557, 831, 831, 878, 933, 970, 1022, 1039)
out <- sapply(K, function(x) {
  for (t in 2:tspan){
    N[t] <- N[t-1]*exp(r*(1-N[t-1]/x))
  } #                              ^ note the x instead of K here 
  N
})
```

Result

```
head(as.data.frame(out))
#        V1       V2       V3       V4       V5       V6       V7       V8       V9      V10
#1 20.00000 20.00000 20.00000 20.00000 20.00000 20.00000 20.00000 20.00000 20.00000 20.00000
#2 26.70800 27.21983 27.22790 27.33125 27.33125 27.34252 27.35427 27.36143 27.37062 27.37342
#3 35.29968 36.88868 36.91432 37.24457 37.24457 37.28077 37.31856 37.34160 37.37119 37.38022
#4 46.04258 49.70798 49.76899 50.56016 50.56016 50.64751 50.73882 50.79455 50.86620 50.88810
#5 59.07051 66.47804 66.60632 68.28529 68.28529 68.47241 68.66838 68.78819 68.94243 68.98963
#6 74.28092 88.03152 88.28178 91.59706 91.59706 91.97116 92.36397 92.60462 92.91501 93.01011
```